# How to use Jquery Ajax with Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-6

I have some trouble when I wanna use Jquery Ajax on laravel, my trouble is when I wanna link to my controller the method is always give me error like this :

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

But in my route list, the url of my controller is already on `POST` method :

```
+--------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Method | URI                 | Name | Action                                             | Middleware |
|--------|---------------------|------|----------------------------------------------------|------------|
| POST   | monitoring/getValue |      | App\Http\Controllers\MonitoringController@getValue | web        |
+--------+---------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

in my `Web.php` :

```
Route::post('getValue', 'MonitoringController@getValue');
```

in my `Controller.php` :

```
public function getValue(Request $list)
{
   $code_project = $input->project_code;
   echo json_encode($code_project);
}
```

in my `app.js` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#project_code").on("change", function () {
      $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
           }
      });
      const value = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
      $.ajax({
           url: "getValue",
           method: "POST",
           data: { project_code: value },
           async: true,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data) {
                console.log('ok');
           }
      })
 });
});
```

on my `blade.php` :

```
 <select name="project_code" id="project_code">
    <option value="" selected disabled></option>
       @foreach ($project as $list)<option value="{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->project_code }}</option>
       @endforeach
 </select>
```

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Comment: I dont know the reason, but you can solve it by `Route::post('getValue',...` to `Route::any('getValue',...` it will work with get method then

Comment: You did not mention your JQuery version, try to change `method: "POST",` to `type: "POST",`

Comment: oh sorry, my versin of jquery is `3.5.1`

Answer (score 0):

try wit full path on url:

```
url: "/monitoring/getValue",
```

Comment: if I use `/monitoring/getValue` in my browser url will be `monitoring/monitoring/getValue`

Comment: when you add slash on the beginning it whould allways be. `http{s}://hostname.domain{here}`